# Help with Dynamic Topology

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I have just come into sculpting and I have noticed that dyntopo's detail deteriorates depending on the view distance in the viewport.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
Because I would like to have the same level of detail whether I zoom in or out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic Topology](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html) lets you work with three types of detail.

1. **Relative detail**

   > This method uses a detail size based on the number of pixels, and in turn will create topology in that size. Zoom out big details, zoom in small fine details.
2. **Constant Detail**

   > To keep detail uniform across the entire object, Constant Detail can be used. The Detail is based on the percentage of a single Blender Unit.
3. **Brush Detail**

   > Giving more control over the topology, with this method you can create topology based on the brush size. You can increase and lower topology by simply resizing the brush itself. The detail size is based the size of the brush itself, where 100% will create topology the size of the brush ring itself.

You can choose which type to use in the Dyntopo panel just under the detail size.

[image: dyntopo settings]